# Foreach element and add custom data jquery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, addclass

I have this HTML markup

```
 <div class="wizard-step">
 <div class="wizard-step">
 <div class="wizard-step">
 <div class="wizard-step">
```

I must change html with jquery that after loop i get this markup

```
<div id="wizard-step-1" class="wizard-step tab-pane fade in active" data-step="1">
<div id="wizard-step-2" class="wizard-step tab-pane fade" data-step="2">
<div id="wizard-step-3" class="wizard-step tab-pane fade" data-step="3">
<div id="wizard-step-4" class="wizard-step tab-pane fade" data-step="4">
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Succinctly, with jQuery:

```
$('.wizard-step').each(function(k,v) {
    var classToAdd = 'tab-pane fade';
    if (k === 0) {
        classToAdd += ' in active';
    }
    $(v).prop('id', 'wizard-step-' + (k+1)).addClass(classToAdd).attr('data-step', (k+1));    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/h35em5a3/)

Comment: This is the shortes and elegant solution, txanks

Comment: @Gorostas indeed it is. But I still don't understand why you didn't try anything by yourself.

Comment: I have added working fiddle, but i am good at Bootstrap and css, html, jquery is something i am learning @Tomanow, can you help me a little more that i dont write another question, what if i have on some other element active already, please take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9212/

Comment: I think you probably want something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/52VtD/9213/)**: 

// if there are no active wizards, make the first active
    `if (!$('.wizard-step.active').length && i === 0) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }`

Comment: Yes but this has to be like in you answer added, to have that all and that option to

Comment: Txanks mate, this is great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65443/discussion-between-gorostas-and-tomanow).

Answer (score 1):

Have a good study at the jQuery function called `.each()` which can be read about here.

http://api.jquery.com/each/

What you will find is that the call-back function is passed two parameters.  The first is the loop index and the second is the element.  For example

```
$(".wizard-step").each(function(index, element) {
   if(index==0) {
      // Do something for first
   } else {
      // Do something for others
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend wrapping them in a distinct container (I'm sure they are already wrapped in something, but for demonstration purposes, I'd like to ensure it). Once that is done, as below:

**HTML code**

```
<div class="wizard-container">
    <div class="wizard-step"></div>
    <div class="wizard-step"></div>
    <div class="wizard-step"></div>
    <div class="wizard-step"></div>
</div>
```

... all you have to do is get the `.wizard-container .wizard-step` elements with a simple jQuery select:

**Javascript code**

```
var wsteps = $('.wizard-container .wizard-step');
```

Once we have those elements, we just have to iterate over them. For this use either a `for` cycle:

**Javascript code**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= wsteps.length; i++)
{
    wsteps[i].attr('data-step', i);
    // HTML5 browsers will support:
    // wsteps[i].data('step', i);

    wsteps[i].addClass('wizard-step');
    wsteps[i].addClass('tab-pane');
    wsteps[i].addClass('fade');

    if (i == 1)
    {
        wsteps[i].addClass('in');
        wsteps[i].addClass('active');
    }
}
```

or using jQuery's built-in `.each()`, that is designed especially for iterating over a set of elements returned by a jQuery select:

**Javascript code**

```
var n = 1;
wsteps.each(function () {
wsteps[i].attr('data-step', n);
    // HTML5 browsers will support:
    // wsteps[n].data('step', n);

    wsteps[n].addClass('wizard-step');
    wsteps[n].addClass('tab-pane');
    wsteps[n].addClass('fade');

    if (n == 1)
    {
        wsteps[n].addClass('in');
        wsteps[n].addClass('active');
    }
    n++;
});
```

Both approaches have their minor cons/pros, but at this scale, it is purely a design choice.